# how to align menu items horizontally

Tags: android

How to create menu items aligned horizontally in the first row like google chrome

[image]

I created the first item with a menu child but by this way i got a row that send me to the other menu, So how to do that using menu file ? i don't want to use Dialog

Here is my menu file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:id="@+id/toolbar_menu"
        android:visible="true">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_tabs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tabs_24dp"
        android:title="@null"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon_row_menu_id"
        android:title="@null"
        android:visible="true">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_back"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_24dp"
                android:title="@string/go_back" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_forward"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_24dp"
                android:title="@string/go_forward" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_bookmark_page"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_star_border_24dp"
                android:title="@string/bookmark_this_page" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_download_page"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_download_24dp"
                android:title="@string/download_page" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_info"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_24dp"
                android:title="@string/view_site_information" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_new_tab"
        android:title="@string/new_tab" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_new_incognito_tab"
        android:title="@string/new_incognito_tab" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_bookmarks"
        android:title="@string/bookmarks" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_history"
        android:title="@string/history" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_downloads"
        android:title="@string/download" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And here how i use it :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mainMenu = menu;
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/01/android-custom-horizontal-icons-menu.html

Comment: But in this exemple he didn't use menu file

Comment: did you tried to group the icons together with <group> icons </group>

Comment: Yes, Nothing chnage the items still open i second menu when i click the first row

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259995/how-to-make-overflow-menu-like-chrome-app

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks for for comment, i just found a source code of AndroidChromium https://github.com/JackyAndroid/AndroidChromium , in this project they have used menu file like me, but i don't figure how they display the items horizontally in the same row.

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui welcome happy to help you

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui please than ans your self for this question so other user cannuse it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_name"` property of item tag like

```
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_id"
android:title="@string/title"
 app:showAsAction="never"
app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_name"/>
```

and your `layout_name` is any layout file like

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

// add your horizontal menu item here

```
</LineearLayout>
```

and you can  access this item

```
 @Override 
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_id);
    Linearlayout rootView = (LinearLayout)item.getActionView();
    YourControlClass control = (YourControlClass) 
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.control_id); 
    return true; 
    }
```

Comment: Same problem nothing change

Comment: Have you used a horizontal layout in menu item

Comment: yes of course i do

Comment: Also there isn't settings flag for app:showAsAction

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: did you try android:showAsAction instead of app:showAsAction ?

Comment: i got compile error when i put android:showAsAction,

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with PopUp window this may help you check above codes

popup.xml layout file not menu,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
              android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        //your images with horizontal

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       // your vertical list view
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and you can Add the following code to the onClick() method:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                        popupView,
                        ActionMenuView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ActionMenuView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setFocusable(true);


                popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

                View parent = view.getRootView();

                popupWindow.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.END,0,0);
```

Comment: I have already said i don't want Dialog or PopupWindow i want to make it with menu file

Comment: @AmineHarbaoui  You can't have custom views for your overflow menu items, so Chrome is not using the standard action bar. It's weird that Google doesn't even use its own standard tools that it pushes for everyone else to use, but that's just how it goes.