# How to create menu with row of icons

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I'm trying to make a menu that is much like typical browsers, with a top row of icons for going forward, bookmarking, etc.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) shows an image with exactly what I want, but it seems to have no information on how to achieve it.

[image]

Is this a feature that is built in to menus, or is this a custom view?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way in the stock overflow menu to have that row of icons at the top, though the rest is all standard behavior. I would assume that this is some custom work in that app.

Comment: If this is the case, it seems very weird that they would showcase a custom layout in their own official documents. I may look into custom menu item views, though I do hope there is a better solution

Comment: "it seems very weird that they would showcase a custom layout in their own official documents" -- this might not make my Top 100 issues with the docs, so I'm less surprised.

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259995/how-to-make-overflow-menu-like-chrome-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Menu item in Overflow menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030579/custom-menu-item-in-overflow-menu)