# Overflow inner menu icons beside each other

Tags: java, android, icons, alignment, overflow

How would I go about putting overflow icons beside each other instead of like a listview

Picture attached for reference[chrome overflow icons beside each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZhcV.jpg)

Comment: hope this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259995/how-to-make-overflow-menu-like-chrome-app

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply Umar, much appreciated